# Flutter equivalent of Sencha's NestedList?

Tags: flutter

I'm searching for an equivalent of [Sencha NestedList](https://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.4/2.4.2-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.dataview.NestedList)

In the example ^^ you can click on `Drinks` to see how  it works. You can see the JSON data by clicking `Code Editor`.

So it's basically a list that takes a nested JSON object and automatically creates nested List with navigation.

Is there an equivalent in Flutter?

Comment: It's just a `ListView` combined with `Navigator.push`